# Get value from a hashtable during runtime from another class

Tags: java, hashtable, rmi

I have two classes.

```
class Question
{
  Hashtable<Integer, String> hs;

  void populateHashTable();
  //to populate hashtable during runtime. 
}

class QuestionGetter
{
  String s; 
  int x;
  //I want string s to hold the value of the key x.
}
```

The hashtable in Question class gets populated only during the runtime. 
I am using RMI concept to run two classes which communicate with each other and retrieve values. So, in the question class, I will add multiple questions along with its question number, which I want to retrieve in the QuestionSetter class where I input question key.

How do I implement this?

Comment: RMI allows you to use classes like they're local so you should have a remote caller class in your local application. Can you draw up a class diagram for us so we can see what's going on where?

Answer (score 1):

You must have a reference of a `Question` object in your `QuestionGetter` class:

```
class QuestionGetter{

   Question question;

   //constructors

   public void add(String s, int x){
      question.hs.put(x, s);
   }
}
```

Comment: I run the Question Class, where I add questions during runtime. So having an instance of Question in QuestionGetter wont create a new instance of question and have an empty hash table?

Comment: That depends if you use the same instance everywhere in your application (see the Singleton pattern) or you create many instances

Answer (score 0):

At first, I assume from your description that your `Question` class is indeed a `QuestionCollection` since it contains multiple questions within its `Hashtable`.

Now, there are two possibilities depending on what you want:

If you want to use only one `QuestionCollection` (since it is populated during runtime anyway), you might want to declare its fields and methods `static`. Now you can just `QuestionCollection.getHs().get(x)` with a provided `int x` in `QuestionGetter` (you will have to insert a static getter-Method provided by your `QuestionCollection` class since you don't want to access the hs directly). This is a very simple but weak solution.

If you might want to use multiple `QuestionCollection`s, you need to pass your `QuestionGetter` an instance of `QuestionCollection` so that it knows which `QuestionCollection` to get the questions from. In this case, rickyalbert's answer applies.